# ImageView not showing bitmap after reappearing on screen API < 23

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap, imageview

I came across a weird issue of the android framework again:
I have an activity which displays detailed information on an object. It is designed to look like a "floating" activity, meaning it overlays the `MainActivity` and can be dismissed by a simple swipe down from the user.

---

### Screenshot

[image: As you can see, the activity overlays its parent.]

---

### How it's done (wrong?)

Because setting the window background to `@android:color/transparent` lead to ugly side effects, I'm using a custom `ImageView` as the background (I modified this one by Chris Banes https://github.com/chrisbanes/philm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/philm/in/view/BackdropImageView.java):

```
public class BackdropImageView extends ImageView {
    private static final int MIN_SCRIM_ALPHA = 0x00;
    private static final int MAX_SCRIM_ALPHA = 0xFF;
    private static final int SCRIM_ALPHA_DIFF = MAX_SCRIM_ALPHA - MIN_SCRIM_ALPHA;

    private float mScrimDarkness;
    private float factor;
    private int mScrimColor = Color.BLACK;
    private int mScrollOffset;
    private int mImageOffset;

    private final Paint mScrimPaint;

    public BackdropImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mScrimPaint = new Paint();
        factor = 2;
    }

    public BackdropImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mScrimPaint = new Paint();
        factor = 2;
    }

    private void setScrollOffset(int offset) {
        if (offset != mScrollOffset) {
            mScrollOffset = offset;
            mImageOffset = (int) (-offset / factor);
            offsetTopAndBottom(offset - getTop());

            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }

    public void setFactor(float factor) {
        this.factor = factor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (mScrollOffset != 0) {
            offsetTopAndBottom(mScrollOffset - getTop());
        }
    }

    public void setScrimColor(int scrimColor) {
        if (mScrimColor != scrimColor) {
            mScrimColor = scrimColor;

            ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        }
    }

    public void setProgress(int offset, float scrim) {
        mScrimDarkness = ScrollUtils.getFloat(scrim, 0, 1);
        setScrollOffset(offset);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        // Update the scrim paint
        mScrimPaint.setColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(mScrimColor,
                MIN_SCRIM_ALPHA + (int) (SCRIM_ALPHA_DIFF * mScrimDarkness)));

        if (mImageOffset != 0) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(0f, mImageOffset);
            canvas.clipRect(0f, 0f, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight() + mImageOffset + 1);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mScrimPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        } else {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mScrimPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the activity, I create a snapshot of the current activity and then save it to cache, passing it's path through `Intent.putExtra(String key, String value);` :

```
public static Intent createOverlayActivity(Activity activity) {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(activity, OverlayActivity.class);
    View root = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    Rect clipRect = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
            .getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(clipRect);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            root.getWidth(),
            root.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    );

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawRGB(0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE);

    // Quick fix for status bar appearing in Lollipop and above
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        canvas.translate(0, -clipRect.top / 2);
        canvas.clipRect(clipRect);
    }
    root.draw(canvas);

    try {
         File file = new File(activity.getCacheDir(), "background.jpg");
         FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

         bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
         stream.flush();
         stream.close();

         bitmap.recycle();
         startIntent.putExtra("bgBitmap", file.getPath());

         Log.d(TAG, "Rendered background image.");
    } catch (IOException e) {               
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return startIntent;
}
```

And in the `OverlayActivity`'s `onCreate()` I receive the path to the cached file and load the Bitmap into the `ImageView`:

```
Bitmap screenshot = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra("bgBitmap"));
if (screenshot == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have to provide a valid bitmap!");
}

/* BackdropImageView is an ImageView subclass allowing
 *  me to darken the image with a scrim using the slide offset value */
backdropImageView = new BackdropImageView(this);
backdropImageView.setId(android.R.id.background);

backdropImageView.setFactor(1.125f);
backdropImageView.setScrimColor(Color.BLACK);
backdropImageView.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
backdropImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

---

### The issue

As you can see in the screenshot above, it works pretty decent on devices running API 23, but **not** on devices below. 
Here the image is shown when the activity slides in, until completely covered, but when I the slide down again, the image is gone and the `ImageView` just shows a solid grey:

[image]

---

### Update

I've figured out that the issue has to hide somewhere in the `BackdropImageView` class, since a simple `ImageView` works.

Any ideas on what could cause this weird issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try adding the lines:

`backdropImageView.setFactor(1.125f);
backdropImageView.setScrimColor(Color.BLACK);
backdropImageView.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
backdropImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

to your Activity's **onStart()** event?

Comment: Yes, I tried this. Still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like I focused too much on the actual image loading than on the view itself.

I found out that the problem was related to the use of `offsetTopAndBottom(offset - getTop());` in the subclass. Somehow this makes the `ImageView` disappear sometimes (still not sure when exactly) on Android Versions previous to Marshmallow, although it was still in the right position in the view hierarchy.

**So here's my work-around:**
When I removed those lines of code, it worked. Because I needed to offset the view to create a parallax scrolling effect, I moved this functionality out of the view subclass. What I'm doing now is simply calling `View.setTranslationY(float)` everytime before `BackdropImageView.setProgress(int, float)` in any scrolling related callback I'm using.

Somehow this works perfectly fine.